# What is mockito and why is it screwing with my JUNIT tests?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Mockito keeps intercepting a function I made in a DAO and randomly returning 0. I would like for the function to actually run. Where can I configure this mockito beast to leave the function alone?

Debugger jumps in here instead of going into my spring dao:

```
 public Object intercept(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy methodProxy)
        throws Throwable {
    if (objectMethodsGuru.isEqualsMethod(method)) {
        return proxy == args[0];
    } else if (objectMethodsGuru.isHashCodeMethod(method)) {
        return hashCodeForMock(proxy);
    }

    MockitoMethodProxy mockitoMethodProxy = createMockitoMethodProxy(methodProxy);
    cglibHacker.setMockitoNamingPolicy(mockitoMethodProxy);

    MockitoMethod mockitoMethod = createMockitoMethod(method);

    FilteredCGLIBProxyRealMethod realMethod = new FilteredCGLIBProxyRealMethod(mockitoMethodProxy);
    Invocation invocation = new Invocation(proxy, mockitoMethod, args, SequenceNumber.next(), realMethod);
    return handler.handle(invocation);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome to be funny but first make sure to ask the question properly. We need to see the method under tests, testing method and results of execution if there are any. Remove anything that could expose the business logic, of course.

Comment: the method just queries the database and is like any other method in the dao class. My testing method is running Junit tests someone else has made on a function that calls the function which mockit intercepts. I just want to know what mockit is and how/where is it configured from. i dont know what code to add since i dont know how mockit works and where its configured.

Comment: Actually from seeing the code I think you are facing Mockito, http://code.google.com/p/mockito/, which is one of the best java mocking frameworks. I would suggest you learn to love it, cause it can make your life (and your tests) way easiert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is mockito?

[MockIto](http://mockito.org/) (and [JMockIt](http://jmockit.org/) as I took the original question) are mock APIs, they allow developers to write tests which are isolated from the rest of the application or other external resources (such as a database).

> why is it screwing with my JUNIT tests?

As who ever wrote the test decided they do not want this test to hit the database. So they used mockito to prevent this from happening.

> Where can i configure this mockito beast to leave the function alone?

Find the developer who wrote this test (or the test you are basing your current test on). Work with them to understand mocking frameworks.

Comment: *"and JMockIt as the question originally inquired about"* OP wrote "mockit" and the code uses "mockito", so why do you think OP asked about "jmockit"? What do I miss here?